# How to find Youtube video duration with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get the video duration using Selenium with python 3. The code is working properly with small videos (I've tried up to 30 minutes). But with longer videos, nothing is shown. I can't find any solution.

My Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, os

firefox = webdriver.Chrome()

#youtube_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEx-SBpZP_M"  # Short Video
youtube_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMWM2uN8WCQ" # Long Video

firefox.get(youtube_url)

number_of_views = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector('#count > yt-view-count-renderer > span.view-count.style-scope.yt-view-count-renderer')
print(number_of_views.text)

duration = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector('#movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > div > span.ytp-time-duration')
print(duration)
print(duration.text)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding some wait time to locate element? and does your code check for ads on youtube? as that might be interrupting locating the element.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with all these solutions is if the element is visible or not.

I.E.

```
cur_time = driver.find_element_by_class_name("ytp-time-current").text
print(cur_time)
```

It will only print the cur_time if my mouse is hovering over the video and the element is showing.  Otherwise if the video playback time isn't showing selenium will not be able to grab the element.  Here's a GIF showing this to be the case.

https://i.imgur.com/bmWdC7A.gif

You need to execute javascript on the page to get the current time and duration.  Youtube Player API has functions for both.

```
video_dur = self.driver.execute_script(
                    "return document.getElementById('movie_player').getCurrentTime()")

video_len = self.driver.execute_script(
                    "return document.getElementById('movie_player').getDuration()")

video_len = int(video_len) / 60

print(f"{video_dur}/{video_len})
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eUGQ.gif

This will continue to work even if I am not on the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGf7L.gif

Answer (score 0):

just use this:

```
duration = firefox.find_element_by_class_name('ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-duration')
print(duration)
print(duration.text)
```

Comment: It prints nothing. Just newlines for print.
The WebElement object is being printed. But after that, only newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
duration = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='ytp-time-duration']")[0]

print(duration.text)
```